# Will TSQL return faster results than stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that works fine previously. It took 4 to 5 secs to get the results.

I didn't used this stored procedure for the past two months. When I call the same procedure now it takes more than 5 minutes to produce the result.
(There is no records populated to my source tables in the past two months)

I converted the stored procedure and executed as TSQL block it is back to normal. But when I convert back to stored procedure again it is taking more than 5 minutes.

I am wondering why it is behaving like this. I used 6 table variables. I just populating those table variables to get the desired results by joining all those.

I already tried the below options

```
With Recompile at the stored procedure level
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
sp_updatestats
```

but there is no improvement. When I execute it as TSQL it works fine.

Please suggest me any ideas to optimize the stored procedure.

Comment: when was the last time you ran `UPDATE STATISTICS` on your source tables?

Comment: I ran sp_updatestats few minutes before twice at the database level end up with no improvements

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing issues or something similar. Try optimize for unknown: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature.aspx

Comment: In your queries, try add `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` (as the last clause) to prevent parameter sniffing. For syntax, explanation, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx).

Comment: You mean I have to add this hint to all of my sql queries inside the sp

Comment: Thanks you all for your immediate suggestions on this. I will make the changes and let you know my comments

Comment: Thanks everyone. @TT in particular.  I would have select your answer if you put your comment in the answer section anyhow I have vote up your comment.

Comment: @NewUser `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` is not the only way. 1) Query with hint `option (recompile)` hint 2) Stored procedure defined as `ALTER PROCEDURE ... WITH RECOMPILE` 3) Bind arguments to local variables. [Related article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx)

Comment: @NewUser Also with argument `I converted the stored procedure and executed as TSQL block it is back to normal. But when I convert back to stored procedure again it is taking more than 5 minutes.` It seems that you miss differences between parametrized SP vs local variable. Looks similiar but they are different things. [Related video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNUArv_DXn4)

Comment: @lad2025: I read the article. It was nice Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your queries, add `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` (as the last clause) to prevent parameter sniffing. For syntax and explanation, see the documentation on [Query Hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx).

What SQL Server does the first time it runs a Stored Procedure is optimize the execution plan(s) for the parameters that were passed to it. This is done in a process that is called `Parameter Sniffing`.

In general, execution plans are cached by SQL Server so that SQL Server doesn't have to recompile each time for the same query. The next time the procedure is run, SQL Server will re-use the execution plan(s) for the queries in it... However, the execution plan(s) might be totally inefficient if you call it (them) with different parameters.

The option I gave you will tell to the SQL compiler that the execution plan should not be optimized for *specific* parameters, but rather for *any* parameter that is passed to the Stored Procedure.

To quote the documentation:

> OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN
>
> Instructs the query optimizer to use statistical data instead of the initial values for all local variables when the query is compiled and optimized, including parameters created with forced parameterization.

In some cases Stored Procedures can benefit from Parameter Sniffing, in some cases they don't. For the Stored Procedures that don't benefit from Paramater Sniffing, you can add the option to each query that uses any of the parameters of the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You may have bad execution plan associated with that proc.
Try this one

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL') WITH MARK_IN_USE_FOR_REMOVAL;
```

You may also find this interesting to read
http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html